# How to deactivate DBGp Proxy in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

In the process of setting up Xdebug I made the mistake to randomly add a DBGp Proxy to my setup in PhpStorm.

Now I want to deactivate it.

Is it actually enough to set a blank host or do I need to do something else in order to ensure that no DBGp Proxy is running? Removing the port number triggers an 'Invalid Settings' error.

[image: Settings DBGp Proxy PhpStorm]

Comment: **1)** Yes, just leave those fields blank. **2)** Even if they are filled, the proxy is not used until you actually "activate" it (register client in it), which needs to be done before starting your debug session. So even if you enter any addresses/keys there, it will not be used until client (PhpStorm) is registered there.

Comment: BTW, DBGp Proxy is a separate software/script that you need to install manually on your server. IDE can only connect there, it does not install or runs it. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/multiuser-debugging-via-xdebug-proxies.html#download-install-dbgp-proxy